# Add value to Calculate field

Tags: python

No value in output table `circ2D`:

Need to add field `circ2D` add fill with value `circ2D` for each polygon:

```
arcpy.AddField_management(theme, "circ2D", "DOUBLE", field_length=13) 

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(theme, ["FID","SHAPE@"]):  
    print ("Polygon # {}: ".format(row[0]))

    for part in row[1]:  # Inside the polygon

        xCoords = []
        yCoords = [] 
        zCoords = [] 
        for pnt in part:

        print (" {}, {}, {} ".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y, pnt.Z))
        xCoords.append(pnt.X)
        yCoords.append(pnt.Y)
        zCoords.append(pnt.Z) 

        perim2D = lab4_arcpy_module.definePerimeter(xCoords, yCoords)  

        area2D = lab4_arcpy_module.defineArea(xCoords, yCoords)  

        cirRatio2D = lab4_arcpy_module.defineCircularRatio(area2D, perim2D) 
arcpy.CalculateField_management(theme, "circ2D", str(cirRatio2D))
```

But cirRatio2D actually calculated  and goes in print statement.

[image]

Output file  does not have this value in the table. 
[image]

What can be a problem?

Comment: Hello @Anna… what is your question?

Comment: fields for each polygon have value 0.  On the picture above.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot understand what you are asking.  It looks like you have some values of 0 in an excel spreadsheet, but you expected some other number.  We can't tell what the problem might be because you haven't shown us the code needed to produce the console output (your first picture) or the spreadsheet output (your second picture).  So we really have no idea what might be wrong.  The `arcpy` code you are using seems to be very specific.  Maybe you could get better help from the developers or user forum.